# ASP.NET MVC3 Razor - Auto-complete Tutorial?

Tags: autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How do you implement auto-complete with ASP.NET, MVC3, and Razor?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/jQueryCodeSamplesMVC/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use [jQuery UI Autocomplete control](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) along with an mvc action that returns a JsonResult with the right data

Answer (score 6):

This isn't using Razor but translating it from webforms to razor is pretty trivial:
http://tpeczek.com/2010/05/jquery-autocomplete-in-aspnet-mvc.html