# What is the proper synatx using Mvc3 Razor for <%= %> from Mvc2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, syntax, razor

In attempting to update working code from Mvc2 to Mvc3 using the Razor engine, we found that this syntax no longer works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = <% =  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>
</script>
```

A previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033060/asp-net-mvc3-razor-auto-complete-tutorial) indicated this to be "pretty trivial" but we are not finding that so. And the [sample](http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2010/05/jquery-autocomplete-in-aspnet-mvc.html) pointed to does not appear to use either json2 nor JavaScriptSerializer().

In the instant case we may choose to use an alternate method; however, it would still be valuable to know if the above line could/should work to transfer data from the @Model into a javascript variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Html.Raw()` is equivalent to `<%= %>` and `@Html.Encode()` is equivalent to `<%: %>`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var initialData = @Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model))
</script>
```

Comment: A further thing to note, in Razor, by default all code when being replaced with their literals are already Html encoded (so you don't need to use @Html.Encode)

Comment: @Skuld - Only when doing something like `@variable` or `@Model.Foo`.  If you do `@{ variable }` or `@{ Model.Foo }` then you need to use the helper, or return an `MvcString` or similar.

Comment: @MystereMan @ { variable } isn't legal syntax to render out anything, {} tells razor to do a code block, not to display text to the browser

Comment: @Skuld - That's my point, when using a code block like that it doesn't automatically encode.  And the syntax is legal (not counting the missing semicolon), it just won't write anything.

Comment: @MystereMan that kind of makes it a mute point, cause when you do want to render the text it'll be html encoded, unless you specificly use the raw helper method.

Comment: @Skuld - That's why I said "You have to use a helper, or return an MvcString, returning an MvcString will not encode it either.